# ATmega32u2 example circuit sanity check

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, debugging, avrdude

I'm working on a project and have decided to make it with the ATmega32u2. In the process I am trying to make an ATmega32u2 breakout board which only has the required components to run the device (crystal, capacitors, resistors, header pins.) I've never tried to make a circuit for an MCU other than an ATmega328p, and I'm not very experienced with this, so I tried the example referenced in 20-3 in the datasheet. I made a breakout board and soldered the chip and passive components, and everything looks good physically.

The problem is that when I plug in the ICSP and try AVRdude, I get device signature 0x00. Is there a problem with my circuit or is it more likely that it's not soldered correctly?

I've tried 2 boards, one with a crystal and one without a crystal, and neither worked. If I remember correctly it's shipped to run with an internal oscillator, so I don't think that would have changed anything.

I've used the same process to program fuses and flash of an ATmega328p, so I don't think it's a problem with the programmer, which is an Arduino Uno programmed as an ICSP.

[image]

[image]

Comment: examine the Arduino Leonardo schematic diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These connections appear correct for powering the AtMega32u2, and for programming it using the serial downloading function (see section 25.8 of the AtMega32u2 datasheet.)

"Arduino Uno ICSP" isn't a single product, unless you mean using an Arduino Uno *as* a programmer, programmed with the ArduinoISP vendor code. In that case, you should verify that you've wired it correctly - it's not a simple "connect one ICSP header to other ICSP header." In particular, the RST connection must come from a GPIO, not from the Arduino Uno's ICSP's RST pin. [The documentation](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP) for the ISP code instructs you to use pin 10 on an Uno for this; verify your other wiring against this documentation as well.

During programming, check that you are getting 5V on VCC - this should be working if you're using ArduinoISP which instructs you to connect the programmer's 5V supply to VCC. (In contrast to many programmers which use VCC as a reference input.) Also check that you are getting 0V on RST - serial downloading only occurs while the AtMega32u2 is held in reset.

Comment: i've updated the question, its an arduino programmed as an ISP. i think i have the wiring correct, from the programmer.  reset goes from 0 to 5V, mosi same, but the miso only has less than 1V.  So it doesn't appear to be able to respond.  I don't even know if its booting now...

Answer (score 0):

The MCU doesn't ship to use an internal oscillator, it uses an external crystal by default (that is unclear in the datasheet, conflicting info) 8Mhz works for sure 16Mhz should work but usb won't.  It turns out I fried one board that I had the crystal on, and the second one works fine with an 8Mhz crystal on it. Thanks everyone for trying to help, and verifying my schematic.

Comment: (effective line breaks in markdown: append two blanks to preceding line - *and* separate with a *newline*)

Comment: "oscillator". The oscillator is in the MCU, regardless. What's external is the "resonator" (either quartz crystal or ceramic). A crystal is a resonator, not an oscillator.

Comment: @DavideAndrea true I was a bit burnt out when I wrote that. thanks